# Calculate a variable using 2 Mysql tables and make a select based on that variable

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I own an online game in which you become the coach of a rugby team and I recently started to optimize my database. The website uses CodeIgniter framework.

I have the following tables (the tables have more fields but I posted only those which are important now):

```
LEAGUES: id
STANDINGS: league_id, team_id, points
TEAMS: id, active
```

Previously, I was having in the LEAGUES table a field named teams. This was representing the number of active teams in that league (of which users logged in recently).
So, I was doing the following select to get a random league that has between 0 and 4 active teams (leagues with less teams first).

```
SELECT id FROM LEAGUES WHERE teams>0 AND teams<4 ORDER BY teams ASC, RAND( ) LIMIT 1
```

Is there any way I can do the same command now without having to add the teams field?
Is it efficient? Or It's better to keep the teams field in the database?

LATER EDIT

This is what I did until now:

```
    function test()
{
    $this->db->select('league_id, team_id');
    $this->db->join('teams', 'teams.id = standings.team_id');
    $this->db->where('active', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get('standings');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

The function returns all inactive teams alongside with their league_id.
Now how do I count the number of inactive teams in each league and how to I sort them after this number?

Comment: Are teams without points recorded in STANDINGS with a zero, or are they not there until they have points?

Comment: All teams are recorded in STANDINGS.

Comment: You'll have to join 2 tables & use count in order to get the result you want.

Comment: I've added a later edit with the function I writter. I don't know where to use the count. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select league_id
from standings s
join teams t on t.id = s.team_id and t.active
group by 1
having count(*) < 5
```

Comment: What does "group by 1" mean? And in the STANDINGS all the teams (active and inactive) are recorded.

Comment: Try that now - I added check for active. "Group by 1" means group by column number 1 in the select clause. It is the same as coding "group by league_id" but faster the read and write for humans